# COMException caused by Application.EditClear Method

Tags: ms-project

I have a COMException caused by the following code

```
MSProject.Application mspApp;
bool result = mspApp.SelectColumn(Constants.ACTUALS_RECENT_INDEX, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
mspApp.EditClear(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);
```

The value of result is `true`.

Here's the exception:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x000003EC): An unexpected error occurred with the method.
>
> at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
>
> at Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSProject._MSProject.EditClear(Object Contents, Object Formats, Object Notes, Object Hyperlinks)

Anybody knows the cause of this exception?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the column that is getting selected is a read-only field such as ID, Unique ID, Project, etc.

Make sure the column being selected is the one you really want. You could do this by creating a table at run-time (and apply it) so you can be confident that the user has not changed the active view and/or underlying table.

Comment: Thank you Rachel.
Do you know how to judge if the column is read-only or not?

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that a customized filter is applied while calling EditClear function. This filter will result in no data in the table. The issue disappeared if not applying the filter.